# Compiler optimization issue

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Compiling the following cause `T::f()` to be optimized-out without any warning or error:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    int t;
    void f(); //undefined..
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.t = 1;
    //t.f(); //<-- compiler-error only when used, otherwise optimized-out
    std::cout << t.t;
    return 0;
}
```

Background: I used stub-declarations for functions in a class with intention to later define and use them. 'Later' never came, and my code compiled & the compiler issued no warnings or errors about these stubs.

Is this expected from the compiler?; shouldn't the compiler at least issue warnings?

Comment: compiler error is different that linker error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an "optimization". C++ compiler lets you declare anything that you wish, provided that the declaration is valid syntactically, and does not reference undefined types. This is not specific to member functions: non-member functions and global variables can be declared without providing a corresponding definition.

It turns out that neither the compiler nor the linker are in a good position to complain about unfulfilled declaration. Even issuing a warning would be problematic due to the possibility of separate compilation.

Compiler will not complain, because it knows that another cpp file may provide the definition, and by the time the linker runs, the declaration is gone: linker works with definitions and references, while declarations are for the compiler.

From a comment:

> There are hundreds (or even thousands) "not called by app" functions
>   in system .h files. The compiler doesn't know where the code resides:
>   either in your .cpp source, or in precompiled .obj/.o, or in .dll/.so
>   etc.etc. It's linker's duty, not the compiler's one. So the compiler
>   silently ignores every signature without "body". –  user4419802

Comment: *Of course* the linker is in a position to complain'. It doesn't find the definition of the declared function: it complains. Do you seriously mean to assert that this program links successfully? It doesn't.

Comment: @EJP Linker has no idea of anything declared, unless it is also used. That's why OP's program links perfectly fine, unless he uncomments the call of `T::f()`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler hasn't optimized anything out because there was nothing there to optimize out in the first place. When you declared `void T::f();` all you did was add a method signature to the compiler's internal dictionary, if you like. You never gave the method a corresponding body and you never called it so it simply 'never happened'.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler issue a warning (at least) that "there was nothing there" for this "method signature" dictionary-entry?

Comment: @slashmais There are hundreds (or even thousands) "not called by app" functions in system .h files. The compiler doesn't know where the code resides: either in your .cpp source, or in precompiled .obj/.o, or in .dll/.so etc.etc. It's linker's duty, not the compiler's one. So the compiler silently ignores every signature without "body".

Comment: @slashmais Well, dasblinkenlight already told mostly the same. It will be possibly duplicate to make another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know whether you're going to declare `T::f()` in another compilation unit, and it doesn't care, because it 'knows' you will get a *linker* error if you don't.